# ASP.NET MVC and Cloud Hosting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hosting, cloud, cloud-hosting

Has anyone had any experience running an ASP.NET MVC (2) app in one of the (decent) cloud hosting services?  Which providers support this?

Additionally - how does session state work in these services - all ok?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We run it on Amazon EC2 without problems (Windows Server 2008)

Comment: All they give you are plain virtual machines, you have to set the whole IIS configuration up yourself. Multiple instances can talk to each other and you could put session state into a session state service, SQL, memcached or whatever. It's your choice.

Answer (score 1):

I run MVC 2 on RackSpace cloud (formerly know as Mosso). I just had to set copy=true for a few of the MVC DLLS as they are not yet installed on the servers.

Apart from that it all works great.